# How to tackle markov chains with transition cost?

Tags: markov-chains

A simple example would be:

I have 3 states, A,B,C

The transition matrix for the chain is:

```
     A     B     C
 A   0.1   0.3   0.6
 B   0.4   0.2   0.4
 C   0.5   0.2   0.3
```

and the transition cost matrix is:

```
     A     B     C
 A   3     5     1
 B   6     8     3
 C   9     2     3
```

so, for each step, say, from A to C, the chance is 0.6, and the cost is 1

If the chain starts from A, and goes on 10 steps (so there are 11 states including A and 10 transitions), how to get the expected sum of the cost?

What's is this kind of problem called? I am able to get the expected number of visited states, but feel a bit confused as the cost is associated with transition but the states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution at step $n$ is $\pi_n=\pi_0T^n$, where $\pi_0$ is the initial distribution, in your case $(1,0,0)$, and $T$ is the transition matrix. The expected cost of the transition from $n$ to $n+1$ is $\pi_nKe$, where  $K$ is the componentwise product of the transition matrix and the transition cost matrix and $e$ is a column vector with all entries $1$. Thus the expected sum of costs of the first $m$ transitions is

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\pi_0T^nKe=\pi_0\left(\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}T^n\right)Ke=(1,0,0)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}T^n\right)\pmatrix{2.4\\5.2\\5.8}\;.
$$

Diagonalizing $T$ allows you to express the sum over its powers as $m$ for the eigenvalue $1$ and $(1-\lambda^m)/(1-\lambda)$ for the other two; in the long run, the eigenvalue $1$ dominates and the cost is approximately

$$m\pi Ke=m\pi\pmatrix{2.4\\5.2\\5.8}\;.$$

The equilibrium distribution is $\pi=\frac1{47}(16,11,20)$ ([computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=transpose%20of%20%7B%7B-9/10,3/10,6/10%7D,%7B4/10,-8/10,4/10%7D,%7B5/10,2/10,-7/10%7D%7D)), so the long-term average cost per step is $1058/235\approx4.5$.

Comment: perfect. btw i don't get what it is following the computation link to wolfram

Comment: @colinfang: The equilibrium distribution is the left eigenvector for eigenvalue $1$. So I subtracted $1$ on the diagonal, took the transpose, computed the right eigenvectors, got $(4/5,11/20,1)$ from Wolfram|Alpha and normalized it to sum to $1$.